# How to show console color in Emacs shell

Tags: terminal, emacs, colors

When I run a command by `smart-compile`, I get string like this.

```
[32mYour bundle is complete![0m
[32mIt was installed into ./vendor/bundle[0m
```

I think `[32m` and `[0m` represent color in console.

Is three way to treat these strings as a color, same as console?

Comment: Are these the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763912/emacs-how-to-change-some-colors-in-m-x-shell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073359/change-emacs-bash-colors-for-ls-command http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256264/how-do-i-get-emacs-shell-mode-to-either-render-or-ignore-my-colors-instead-of

Comment: Sorry, I wrote "in shell", but it happens when I run command from `smart-compile`. I should have written more precisely. I'll rewrite my question.

Comment: And I applied `(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)` then run `smart-compile`, but the color strings remained same as before.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing you `TERM` type in you `.bashrc` file like this:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

Then turn on UTF-8 coding system everywhere, like so:

```
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-language-environment 'utf-8)
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)

(setq locale-coding-system 'utf-8)

(if (boundp 'buffer-file-coding-system)
    (setq-default buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8)
  (setq default-buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8))
```

See if that works!

Comment: I tried what you wrote, but It doesn't work for me. Thanks anyway!